# How to SUM of SUMS of fields with same value in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sum

I have these table: I need to "SUM" all the VALUES with the same KEY1 & KEY2 WHEN KEY3 = X

```
| KEY1 | VALUE1 | KEY2 | VALUE2 | KEY3 |
|   1  |   9    |   2  |   2    |   x  |
|   1  |   10   |   2  |   3    |   x  |
|   2  |   5    |   1  |   8    |   x  |
|   2  |   5    |   1  |   9    |   y  |
```

> SELECT key1 as k1, key2 as k2 FROM table1 WHERE key3 = x

For each result of these query I need to do:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(SUM(case when key1 = k1 then totalamount1 else 0   end),0) + 
COALESCE(SUM(case when key2 = k2 then totalamount2 else 0   end),0) as total
FROM table1
WHERE key3 = x
```

Y need these output:

```
      Total
id 1:  27
id 2:  10
```

How I can join thes two query?

Thanks!

Comment: Seriously, fix your data structure.  The problem isn't "how do I code this" it's "how do I represent this sensibly in a database"...

Comment: What is `totalamount1` and `totalamount2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to get the result:

```
SELECT IF(i.i,t.key1,t.key2) AS `id`
     , SUM(IF(i.i,t.value1,t.value2)) AS `Total`
  FROM table1 t
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1) i
 WHERE t.key3 = 'x'
 GROUP
    BY IF(i.i,t.key1,t.key2)
```

[SQL Fiddle demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7599f/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7599f/1)

---

The "trick" I used is to get two sets of rows, by performing a cross join of table1 with a set containing exactly two rows; those two rows can be distinguished from each other with a conditional test.

Since the value of `i.i` will either be `1` or `0`, that means it will evaluate to TRUE and FALSE as a conditional test within an IF function.

We can extract (key1, value1) from one set of rows, and extract (key2,value2) from the other set, essentially, creating a result set like this:

```
| i | keyN | valueN | 
| 1 |   1  |   9    | 
| 1 |   1  |   10   | 
| 1 |   2  |   5    | 
| 0 |   2  |   2    | 
| 0 |   2  |   3    | 
| 0 |   1  |   8    |
```

Now, it's just a matter of doing a `SUM(valueN) GROUP BY keyN`

---

The query above could be rewritten in (more portable) SQL-92 style:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN i.i = 1 THEN t.key1 ELSE t.key2 END AS `id`
     , SUM(CASE WHEN i.i = 1 THEN t.value1 ELSE t.value2) AS `Total`
  FROM table1 t
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1) i
 WHERE t.key3 = 'x'
 GROUP
    BY CASE WHEN i.i = 1 THEN t.key1 ELSE t.key2 END AS `id`
```

(For Oracle, we'd need to add `FROM DUAL` on each select in the inline view aliased as i.)

---

Comment: Excelent! Thank you I just need it!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to "unpivot" your table:

```
SELECT
  Key,
  SUM(Value) AS Total
FROM (
  SELECT Key3, Key1 AS Key, Value1 AS Value FROM Table1
  UNION ALL SELECT Key3, Key2, Value2 FROM Table1
) NormTable
WHERE Key3 = 'x'
GROUP BY Key
```

You could also move the `WHERE Key3 = 'x'` into *each* of the union queries. That would be faster, but more error prone because you'll need to change it in each query if you need a different `Key3` value. Your call on that one.